# Where threads are located in memory?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, thread-safety, pthreads

hay
I have a question about location of threads in memory,
Where is threads stack located? And is there a way to display it (using gdb, readelf or something similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to display it...using gdb...?

Sure, GDB can show you the stack of any thread. I don't remember the commands, but they're right there in the manual. ISTR, there's one command that will list all of the threads, there's another that you use to tell it which thread you want to look at. Everything else works just like how it works for a single-threaded program.

I think there's also a way you can tell GDB to iterate over the threads (i.e., perform a single command, such as dump the stack, once for each thread in the program.)

> Where is threads stack located?

Um, It's located in memory.

Seriously. Why do you want to know? In most programming environments that I have ever heard of, the entire stack for a thread gets allocated all at once, and it can not grow. There's usually some way for the program to say how big it needs the stack of a new thread to be if the default size is not big enough.

In Linux, the program *typically* would obtain space for a new thread's stack by calling ['mmap(...)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with arguments that allow the OS to choose the virtual address. But, there's no reason why it *has* to work that way. The program could allocate the stack from the heap, if that made any sense.

In other operating systems, there's probably some mechanism similar to mmap that lets the OS choose the address.

---

> if you want an exact answer it is in the memory between heap and stack

If you go back thirty or more years, A process in a Unix-like OS would be given one contiguous block of virtual memory, typically starting at page one (page zero would be unallocated because that's how you get a segfault if the program follows a NULL pointer.) The lowest addresses would contain the program's "text" segment (e.g., its code and immutable strings), then the "data" segment (initialized static variables), then the "bss" segment (uninitialized static variables.)

Everything from the top of the BSS to the top of the given VM region was "wilderness" (i.e., untouched). The program's heap would grow up into the wilderness from the bottom, and its one and only call stack would grow down into the wilderness from the top. If the heap and the stack ever met, then you'd get a "stack overflow" or a `malloc()` error.

Things are more complicated these days, when a program can have dozens or even hundreds of call stacks. Instead of that "wilderness" Linux programs today can use ['mmap(...)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to create additional VM regions--either for a new thread's stack, or to add to the heap, or to map a file into memory for random access.

Comment: @zmlig, see my response, which I tacked on to the end of my "answer," above.